# In LLDB, is it possible script a few simple commands at breakpoint and auto continue without python

Tags: macos, gdb, lldb

In gdb, I can setup a scrip to execute a few simple commands at breakpoint.  For example:

```
set pagination off

b foo.c:119
commands
    bt 10
    cont
end
r
quit
```

Is there an equivalent in lldb?    I know it probably can be done with python inside lldb.   I just prefer simple standard lldb commands if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `breakpoint command add`, LLDB will expect normal debugger commands, not a Python script.

So:

```
b foo.c:119
br co a
> bt 10
> cont
> DONE
```

Comment: Works very well!   Thanks.